# How prevent blurry drawing on canvas when using putImageData?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to use `putImageData` to paint on canvas. But for some reason the painted pixels are blurry and I don't know why. Here is a minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
       html, body, canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

      let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
      ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

      let uarr = new Uint8ClampedArray(4);
      uarr[0] = 0;
      uarr[1] = 0;
      uarr[2] = 0;
      uarr[3] = 255;

      let imgData = new ImageData(uarr , 1, 1);
      ctx.putImageData(imgData, 20, 20);
    </script>      
  </body>
</html>
```

This should paint one black pixel at the `20,20` coordinates, but for some reason it look blurry.

[image]

How can I force to draw sharp edges?

Comment: Not all browsers seem to support this yet. Safari seems to be a holdout. What browser are you using?

Comment: Checked in chrome and Safari

Comment: Oh wait. Try `canvas.width = window.innerWidtht` and `canvas.height = window.innerHeight`. You are currently stretching a standard size canvas to the size of the screen using CSS, but that's not how canvas works, its more like an image with predefined size that can be stretched.

Comment: I feel kind of dumb right now, haha. I have worked with canvas before, dunno how I could have missed that.

Comment: Ha no problem, its when it's staring you straight in the face and you still don't see it. Obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the canvas width and height attributes, as your CSS is stretching a default size canvas to the size of the screen, like stretching a too small image. After that `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled` should work fine.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// This will stretch correctly
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

var uarr = new Uint8ClampedArray(4);
uarr[0] = 0;
uarr[1] = 0;
uarr[2] = 0;
uarr[3] = 255;

var imgData = new ImageData(uarr , 1, 1);
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 20, 20);
```

```css
html, body, canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

As @Kaido mentions in the comments below, `imageSmoothingEnabled` does not really work that way. Check his fiddle for a little bit more of an in-depth look at what it can be used for.

Comment: `imageSmoothingEnabled` only works for `drawImage` method. `putImageData` won't create any anti-aliasing (it is the only canvas API method that doesn't by default), it will just put the raw pixels as they are set in the imageData's data. https://jsfiddle.net/w8deLfo1/

Comment: Good catch, although there are easy ways around this (like a buffercanvas).

Comment: There is nothing to work around, it's just that you don't need to set imageSmoothingEnabled for putImageData.

Comment: True, but I assume there must be a reason for it :)

Comment: You mean a reason for the OP to set this ? I guess it's because he was looking for a solution for his css antialising, and heard about imageSmoothingEnabled, while it won't do anything in his case, since it is really limited to `drawImage`.

Comment: Yeah i know, and i'll probably ad what you said as an update to my post later. Let's say my focus shifted away from the image smoothing when i noticed the stretching. By the way, since pit image data doesn't allow you to stretch the input, it will never make a difference.

Comment: Well yes it could have, check my example fiddle, neither with drawImage nor putImagedata I do resize the source, but putImageData doesn't respect floating coords.

Comment: Updated my post. Your fiddle is slightly more advanced than the scope of this post, but still good stuff.